# How do I add a custom thumbnail for each file I save on my own custom format

Tags: ios, swift, filewrapper

I have defined a new file format for my app on `Target > Info > Document Types` and on `Target > Info > Exported Type Identifiers`.

I have also defined a default icon for these files by adding a `CFBundleTypeIcon` key to the `Additional document type properties` inside `Document Types`.

Now, when I see one of my files on iOS Files, the file shows with that icon.

But because my own files represent a drawing, what I really wanted was to have one different thumbnail per file.

My file is a `package` and I am using FileWrapper to save content inside the package.

I have this on my Info.plist.

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
            <true/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>tb</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>icon.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>MyApp Project</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.example.myAppProject</string>
            </array>

    <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.apple.package</string>
                <string>public.directory</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>MyApp Project</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.example.myAppProject</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>tb</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
```

How do I generate a custom icon for every file I save with this custom format using FileWrapper for the package kind of file? What I mean is, icons that can be seen by iOS Files.app when visualizing files saved by my app.

Comment: You don't actually want to change the icons. Those are static (per file type). What you're looking for is "Quick Look Preview Extensions". See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/237/ and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookthumbnailing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a `Thumbnail Extension` with your app. OS will invoke your extension to ask for a custom thumbnail whenever it needs to.

```
override func provideThumbnail(for request: QLFileThumbnailRequest, _ handler: @escaping (QLThumbnailReply?, Error?) -> Void) {
    // Generate your thumbnail and call the handler
}
```

[Providing Thumbnails of Your Custom File Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklookthumbnailing/providing_thumbnails_of_your_custom_file_types) has all the information you need.

> Implement a Thumbnail Extension to allow the operating system and other apps to display thumbnails of your custom files.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be something that will show the icons if the app is installed on the system. It is there a way to show the icons even if the app is not on the system? On the lines of PDF, JPEG, PNG files, etc?

Comment: Not that I know of.